# MySQL SubQuery / Correlated Query

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm building a user statistics page and trying to display the statistics properly and would love some assistance.

I have a website that offers downloadable files for registered users and I would like to keep track of the downloads and how many times each user downloaded that file as well as how many unique products they downloaded from.

Table: customer_statistics

```
| user |  product_id  |  file_download  |  date_accessed   |
------------------------------------------------------------
| tom  |  1104        |  mp3       |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  video     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  video     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  video     |  2017-05-07 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  video     |  2017-05-08 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1010        |  video     |  2017-05-08 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1077        |  video     |  2017-05-08 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1749        |  photo     |  2017-05-09 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1284        |  video     |  2017-05-09 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1284        |  video     |  2017-05-09 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1065        |  mp3       |  2017-05-09 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1344        |  video     |  2017-05-10 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  2504        |  photo     |  2017-05-10 00:00:00  |
```

I would to display the data as such:

```
Name | Unique Mp3s | Unique Photos | Unique Videos | Total
----------------------------------------------------------
Tom  |    1        |    0          |    3          |  7
Sue  |    1        |    2          |    2          |  6
```

The columns `unique mp3s/photos/videos` show how many unique `product_id` each file type has been downloaded from while the `total` shows the total amount of all file types and occurrences added up for that specific user.

What is the best way to achieve the above result?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: I think you could do something like `select count(*), user, group_concat(file_download SEPARATOR 'RARE_WORD') from table group by user` then explode on the separate (`RARE_WORD`) for the file types and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php. Then output as needed.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Oh, alias the `count(*)` as `total` as well, or just remove it and use the total at the end of the iterating..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way, no subquery required:

```
SELECT user AS `Name`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE file_download WHEN 'mp3' THEN product_id END) AS `Unique Mp3s`
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE file_download WHEN 'photo' THEN product_id END) AS `Unique Photos`
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE file_download WHEN 'video' THEN product_id END) AS `Unique Videos`
  COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) AS `Total`
FROM customer_statistics
GROUP BY user;
```